# flutter <String, String>' has no instance method 'startswith'

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I solve this problem

> flutter <String, String>' has no instance method 'startswith'

I used flutter search bar

```
Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
var searchlist = query.isEmpty
    ? list
    : list.where((element) => element.contains(query)).toList();

return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: searchlist.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(searchlist[index]['name']),
        //subtitle: Text(searchlist[index]['price']),
        leading: Icon(Icons.mobile_friendly),
      );
    });
```

}
}

```
 ` List data = [
 { "url": "images/oppo.png", 
  "name": "oppo A74 Dual", 
  "price": "4000",},

{
  "url": "images/samsung.png",
  "name": "smasung S22 ultra",
  "price": "4000",
  
},
{
  "url": "images/realme.png",
  "name": "realme",
  "price": "4000",
  
}];`
```

Search app bar flutter

Comment: Please embed your code into the question instead of providing an image of it.

Comment: First it is `startsWith`, the spelling is incorrect and second it is used on Strings not Maps.

Comment: Can you suggest to me how to write this part of the code in a correct way

Comment: as @puelo mentioned you should not provide your code as an image, assuming that 'query' is String this is probably what you're trying to do: list.where((element) => element["name"].startsWith(query)).toList();

Comment: thank you for helping it solved   @– Mohamed Oussous